# Python csv file with 200 columns to 200 rows instead

Tags: python, pandas

I have a csv file that has the following columns

> Columns: [RSVR,COMP,Moved!,2020-09-16T07:08:14.820Z
> RSVR,COMP,Moved!,2020-09-16T07:09:56.102Z
> RSVR,COMP,Moved!,2020-09-16T07:12:36.901Z
> RSVR,COMP,Moved!,2020-09-16T07:14:28.983Z
> RSVR,COMP,Moved!,2020-09-16T07:16:43.868Z
> RSVR,COMP,Moved!,2020-09-16T07:18:59.702Z]

The above dataframe is many columns but i would like it in 4 columns and many rows.
Each new row starts with RSVR,

```
    data = pd.read_csv('rsvr.csv' ,sep = 'RSVR')
    print(data.head())
```

Comment: are those your columns? Or is that your data?

Comment: It would help if in your post you attached a screenshot of the current dataframe: the output of `print(data.head())`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `data.transpose()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `data.T` to transpose the dataframe:

Here is an example:

```
>>> data = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random((4,5)),columns=['a','b','c','d','e'])
>>> print(data)

          a         b         c         d         e
0  0.597361  0.974468  0.986410  0.425091  0.924654
1  0.303409  0.346658  0.825752  0.301768  0.179602
2  0.855508  0.146188  0.595827  0.067834  0.574698
3  0.223948  0.154886  0.724820  0.420176  0.007896

>>> data = data.T
>>> print(data)

       0         1         2         3
a  0.597361  0.303409  0.855508  0.223948
b  0.974468  0.346658  0.146188  0.154886
c  0.986410  0.825752  0.595827  0.724820
d  0.425091  0.301768  0.067834  0.420176
e  0.924654  0.179602  0.574698  0.007896
```